# How do I export pipeline runtime duration to CSV

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, export-to-csv, azure-data-factory

I want to export my runtime duration of the each pipeline to CSV. How can this be done or achieved?
The below is scheduled Pipeline which run to end, i can use the the Export CSV button to get duration of these pipelines but each execute pipeline got so many individual jobs(In this example will take P_Weekly_RV_Load_1)  and how can I get those details of all those individual jobs run in p_weekly_RV_Load_! to csv

[image: Triggered Pipeline jobs]

[image: P_Weekly_RV_Load_1 - All jobs in that]

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the Monitoring view in ADF, click on "Pipeline runs" and then "Debug". On the top right you'll see "Export to CSV".

[image]

Comment: Thanks but i need to export individual pipeline runs which is run through main Execute pipeline job. Please see above screenshot

Answer (score 0):

When you say individual jobs I am assuming you mean the activity runs inside of a pipeline. Currently activity level detail is not exported to CSV, just the pipeline details.

To capture activity level detail there are a couple of options:

1. Use diagnostics settings and send the Activity Runs to storage, Log Analytics, or Event Hubs. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-configure-diagnostics/ on how to set this up.
2. Use the SDKs via REST, Powershell, etc. to query the activity run endpoints and export the data programmatically. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/activity-runs/query-by-pipeline-run as an example.